# How to add new fields to current Form on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

Imagine we have a Form in an HTML page. It is a very common behavior that some fields appear and disappear by filling a particular field or selecting a value for some Radio buttons or Select tags. This could be done using Java Script. I am wondering if it is possible to add some new fields to CURRENT form by triggering an ajax call. Is that possible?

If I want to add some new fields on the page by communicating to the Server through an ajax call, should I add a new form to the page contain those field or I can use my current form?

Comment: Please give some more specification for how you want to add new field. mean in which condition and when. It is possible to add new field in form on fly.

Comment: I want to add a new field (let's say an input field) to my current Form, using triggering an Ajax call after for example clicking on a radio button! I know that it is possible using JavaScript. but in that case this field should be exist on current DOM while it is hide. But, I am wondering if it is possible to have a Form which has for example two input fields at the first and will have three input fields after triggering an Ajax call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just put the code for appending your form in the ajax success callback.
Here is a jsfiddle, assuming you get json from the ajax call.
Just type ajax in the second field (to simulate condition for making ajax call), it will grab a fake json response and will generate extra fields with field names from that data.

http://jsfiddle.net/ua47escq/1/

```
<ul>
<form action="" id ="myform">

<li> some field <input type="text"> </li>
<li> other field <input type="text" id = "myinput"></li>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

</form>
</ul>
<script>
var myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var fakejson = JSON.stringify([{
                "fieldname": "dynamic field1"
            }, {
                "fieldname": "dynamic field2"
            }, {
                "fieldname": "dynamic field3"
            }]);

myinput.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.value == "ajax") {
            sucsess(fakejson);
        }
    });


function appendform(name) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var newinput = document.createElement("input");
    newinput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newinput.setAttribute('name', name);
    li.textContent = name;
    li.appendChild(newinput);
   form.insertBefore(li, submit);


}

function sucsess(data) {

    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    for (key in json) {
        appendform(json[key]["fieldname"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. could you please let me know how I can trigger this ajax call using your code? I understand what you've written but I don't know how to add another field before pressing 'submit' button.

Comment: I made some changes to the fiddle to use jsfiddle json echo for ajax requet
http://jsfiddle.net/ua47escq/7/

Comment: Oh, the ajax function is triggered by an event handler (it starts with myinput.addEventListner), it listens to keyup event on second field, and if word ajax is typed in it triggers ajaxcall() function.So, if you don't press submit after typing word ajax in second field, the event listner will call ajaxcall(). You can can change the logic to fill your praticular needs. So basicly, whenever you call ajaxcall(), it will make the call and create fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally saw the result. But, Just a question. Should I be able to see these new Fields on the DOM? I mean, in the HTML section of the code the Form, only contains two fields. After triggering this ajax call it should contain five fields, and I should be able to see these new fields inside the DOM, right? Since this Form is going to be submitted with all these Fields. Am I right?

Comment: Well, if you are looking at the DOM by view source, it only shows static stuff. To see dynamic changes done by javascript you need to use developer tools. In the browser right click on the newly generated filed and select "inspect element " from menu. The inspector panel will open up and you'll see the new fields. Alternatively, you can press f12 to open developer tools. In the tools panel click on elements tab and you will see the DOM as it changes, live. What browser are you using? Chrome has good developer tools. But all other browsers have dev tools as well.